# Variable Losing Value

Tags: php, oracle10g

I am getting this from the following code when I reach my print statements:

```
This is the for loop value : b
This is the for loop value : b
This is the for loop value : 
This is NOT the for loop value :
```

I am not sure what's going on with the $le variable, why it is one thing inside the for loop and another inside of it.

```
        foreach($this->letdowns AS $ld) 
        {
            $le = "";
            for($i = 0; $i <= sizeof($this->letdowns); $i++)
            {
                $le = $this->letdown_end[$i];
                $msg = "This is the for loop value : " . print_r($le, true) . "<BR>";
                print $msg;
            }
            $msg = "This is NOT the for loop value : " . print_r($le, true) . "<BR>";
            print $msg;

            //$query = "INSERT INTO letdown_events (letdown_line_id, operation_id) "
            $query = "INSERT INTO letdown_events (letdown_line_id, letdown_end, operation_id) "
                    //."values (".$ld->get('id').",".$this->id.")";
                    ."values (".$ld->get('id').",".$le.",".$this->id.")";
            // Make sure this query completes, otherwise rollback the transaction

            var_dump($query);

            if(!$result = mydb::cxn()->query($query)) 
            {
                throw new Exception('An error occurred while trying to create a letdown event for Letdown Line #'.$ld->get('id').': '.mydb::cxn()->error);
            }
        }
```

When I var_dump the variable, it is also coming up blank.

```
string(103) "INSERT INTO letdown_events (letdown_line_id, letdown_end, operation_id) values (1552020000,,1781020000)"
```

Can anyone please point out why I can't use the $le variable outside the loop, I am just looking for a good way to insert it into the database using that query.

Comment: We need to see the array result for `$this->letdown_end`

Comment: This is pretty obvious. See how `This is the for loop value : ` is blank? Well, `$le` is being assigned a blank value in the last iteration of the loop. And now you're referring to that same blank value. See @MarkBaker's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($this->letdowns); $i++)
```

NOT

```
for($i = 0; $i <= sizeof($this->letdowns); $i++)
```

But why not simply use

```
foreach($this->letdowns as $le)
```